# ¿Cómo puedo ver el código fuente de un sitio web Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directivas

¿Hay una forma de ver el código fuente de un sitio web hecho con Angular después de haber compilado?

Es que la directiva `ng-cloak` oculta todo lo que esté dentro del elemento en que se especificó, y solo se muestra una vez el browser ha compilado el sitio.

Y los browsers mustran el código pero parece que antes de compilar ya que la directiva aún se muestra.

¿Existe alguna forma de ver el código a posteriori o alguna forma de por lo menos ver los elementos ocultos, usando Selenium en Python con los web drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede, eso seria una gran vulnerabilidad para cualquiera que quisiera entrar por malos modos en la pagina.
Todo lo que puedes ver lo tienes en el inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Comment: Vale gracias. Y desde Selenium no se puede controlar el inspector para obtener un elemento?

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te sugiero leer [answer], si tienes suficiente reputación puedes realizar un comentario.